# asp.net, ASPxCallback, Force postback in callback?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm using aspxcallback control and I wonder if there's any possiblity to force page postback while performing callback. I mean - in some situation my page require to postback -

```
<dx:ASPxCallback ID="callback" runat="server" OnCallback = "callback_callback" />



protected void callback_callback(object s, CallbackEventArgs e) {
  if (requirePostBack)
    // do Postback
  } else {
    //do callback stuff
  }
}
```

or if was it possible to handle this case in ASPxGridView events?

Comment: Have you looked at [__doPostBack()](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/)?

Answer (score 0):

ASPxCallback is designed to send callbacks only.  If you need to send a postback to the server, you need to use the __doPostBack() method.  This decision (which request to send) should be made at the client side.